# Definition of support of a distribution.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

> **Definition:** On a separable metric space X, the support of a measure
> $\gamma$ is defined as the smallest closed set on which $\gamma$ is
> concentrated, i.e., $$\operatorname{spt}(\gamma):=\bigcap\{A: A\text{ is
>  closed and }\gamma(X\setminus A)=0\}.$$ This is well defined since the
> intersection may be taken countable, due to the separability
> assumption.

I don't really understand the sentence

> This is well defined since the intersection may be taken countable,
> due to the separability assumption.

Why is it a problem if we have an uncountable intersection? Why is the possibly uncountable intersection a countable one if the space is separable?

Comment: It could be that, although the intersection is defined, you don't have the property that $ \gamma(\mathrm{spt}(\gamma)\setminus A)=0 $.

Comment: What do you mean by > closed?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I guess it means closed with respect to the topology corresponding to the metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $X$ is a separable metric space, it has a countable base and so it is hereditarily Lindelöf, i.e. every family of open subsets of $X$ has a countable subfamily with the same union.

We can apply this fact to $\mathcal{O}=\{O \subseteq X\mid \gamma(O)=0\}$ and so get  a countable subfamily $\mathcal{O’}$ with $\bigcup \mathcal{O’} = \bigcup \mathcal{O}$ and as $\mathcal{O’}$ is countable, subadditivity applies and $\gamma(\bigcup \mathcal{O’})=0$. Finally note that the support can then be found as $X\setminus \bigcup \mathcal{O’}$ and is thus well-defined.

The DIeudonné measure on $\omega_1 $ is an example of a Borel measure where this definition of support would not work (the space is not separable metric, “only” hereditarily normal, and locally compact and countably compact, so still quite nice.).

Comment: Note that I reduced the complements of the closed sets to a countable subfamily, so the intersection becomes countable too (de Morgan etc.) This definition would yield $\emptyset$ for the support as we then take an uncountable intersection of tails, really.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "this definition of support would not work"? On the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)#A_nontrivial_measure_whose_support_is_empty) I read that the Dieudonné measure has support $\emptyset$ so for each $x\in\omega_1$ I have to find $A\subset\omega_1$ with $x\notin A$ and $\gamma(\omega_1\setminus A)=0$ right? But what do you take for $A$?

Comment: @edamondo this definition gives $\emptyset$ but this isn’t really what you’d like. The measure is locally trivial but globally nontrivial. Regularity fails at \omega_1$ in the compacificstion $\omeha_1+1$ etc.